# Spring @RequestMapping, 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-code-404

So, I'm trying to learn Spring Framework, but currently I'm stuck on this problem, for some reason my mappings don't work and when I try to access that address I'm getting a 404 error.

Can someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong (both in usage of spring classes and the source of the problem I have described above)?

I'm configuring spring using the example shown in this video: [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BY9YxdMg8I), the code is basically the same, the only difference is package name and the location of the JSP file (could this be the source of my problem?).

The project was made in IntelliJ Idea and is attached to the following link (Google Drive): [Project Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5hopHObea9MMG1aMWV1UlJZX1U/view?usp=sharing)

As my servlet container I'm using Tomcat8 (tried both 9 and 8.5, no cigar).

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.demo.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

package com.demo.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by ARTERC on 1/16/2017.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**WebInit.java**

```
package com.demo.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

@Configuration
public class WebInit extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class};
    }

    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
package com.demo.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.demo.spring")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**home.jsp** path: /web/home.jsp

Comment: you should put your code here.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, forgot to. Done

Comment: So, I forgot to add <packaging>war</packaging> in my pom.xml, but still it didnt fix my problem, it does map urls, but I still get 404 error. It says HTTP Status 404 - /home.jsp so for some reason it cant find my view aka home.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution.

1. Add war plugin to pom.xml
2. Fix web resource directory path (was webapp) [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mym3.png)

Comment: How to add war plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html